# How do I sum a total number of occurrences of a ID number with a specific month and year in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a Excel Master sheet where I am looking to query other sheets within the workbook. What I am trying to do is see How many occurrences of an ID for a Project in a column occur within a month, e.g. how many times does the ID 1367 occur in November. My dates are in the format of e.g 13/11/18 and this cannot be changed as I am just creating a report against a workbook I do not own.

The relevant columns I need are formatted like so:

```
Project:   Project ID:    Date:
a             123         1/01/2018
a             123         2/01/2019
a             123         3/01/2018
a             123
```

This is my SUMIFS function:

```
=SUMIF(PPlanner!$D:$D,Dashboard!$B$6,PPlanner!X:X)
```

This works by itself. My problem is trying to get the ID total for a specific month.

It returns the number of occurrences the ID occurs against a project all together but not against the month specifically. I have tried adding syntax to specify
the month but I am getting errors such as "too many arguments".

Comment: specific month of all years or specific month in specific year?

Comment: A specific month in a specific year e.g. All for November 2018

Comment: In the formula it's SUMIF and not SUMIFS - possible source of "too many arguments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently answered a question that was very similar :
[Excel - Take Average of Monthly Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379402/excel-take-average-of-monthly-data/53380240#53380240)

I think this would answer your question as well, but you have to use `COUNTIFS` instead of `AVERAGEIFS`

As for presentation, I would make a separate list of the months you want to include, and put the formula next to it, instead of the formula next to the actual list of data (as in the other question). As for how to write/input the month, you can put it any way you want, as long as it is a valid date in Excel. With the cell formatting you then can show it as month and year only. This is just to say that a text input `JANUARY 2018` does not work (in a normal cell, eg. a cell that you did not format as text, when you type that into the cell, Excel recognizes this as a date, and will actually put `1/1/2018`).

Oh, and using a Pivot table would work as well, the other answer on the question referenced above also explains how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, how Excel handles dates is very convenient.
For you, the date format doesn't matter. It is simply a number counting days with 0 being December 31st, 1899.

13/11/18 the date is the integer 43417 in-cell value. Excel interprets this as a both date and time together. The whole numbers are the days while the decimals are the time of day as a fraction of the day. 43417.5 would be noon.

So you may use `COUNTIFS` to help here.

```
=COUNTIFS(PPlanner!$X:$X, 1367, PPlanner!$D:$D, ">"&43404, PPlanner!$D:$D, "<"&43435)
```

This is going to look at sheet PPlanner column X and count how many instances of 1367 occur after the last day of October and before the first day of December. There are other ways to accomplish this, but it allows you to count within any date range you want.